# How can I get total result count from google custom search?

Tags: python, google-custom-search

I want to get URL in http://www.malware-traffic-analysis.net/

I want to get url when I insert keyword "nuclear".

but I block because I do not get total count.

this is my sample code.I almost done..

```
import urllib2
import json
import pprint

def customSearch(page,keyword):
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_API_KEY'
        + '&cx=007471739612924802870:ak59oowq-cq&num=10&start='
        + str(page)
        + '1&q='
        + keyword
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(data)
    return data

def getURL(keyword):
    result=[]
    try:
        for i in range(1): # i want to get this range
            data=customSearch(i,keyword)
            for temp in data['items']:
                result.append(temp["link"])
    except:
        None
    content=""
    for i in result:
        content+=(i+"\n")
    f=open(keyword+'.txt',"w")
    f.write(content)
    f.close()

getURL("Nuclear")
```

Comment: I replaced `MY_API_KEY` with a valid api key and fixed the multi-line string for the url and it seemed to work fine. Can you describe the problem more? And not sure what you mean by total count, but the total number of urls is just `len(result)`.

Comment: range(1) only get 1page. but i want to get all page. total result number/10 is page number. so i want to know page number.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only get 10 results per page, and you can only check 10 pages (for a total of 100 results). After that Google's API will start returning 400 Bad Request errors so just change your code to `for i in range(10):`

Comment: @AbdAzrad You could use start=11, start=21, ...etc in the query string to load more results.